# Restricting a Service using Windows Firewall APIs not finding service shortname

Tags: c++, windows-services, windows-firewall-api

I am using the example to restrict all except one port for a specific windows service. I took the example from [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd339611(v=vs.85).aspx) and tried it for OpenVPN windows service. Basically I just edited these two lines:

```
BSTR bstrServiceName = SysAllocString(L"OpenVPNServiceInteractive"); 
BSTR bstrAppName = SysAllocString(L"C:\\Program Files\\OpenVPN\\bin\\openvpnserv.exe");
```

As it needs the shortname and not the display name, I did `sc query` in my console and found for *OpenVPNServiceInteractive*, but when I run it doesn't find the service shortname (it fails the handle and says: *RestrictService failed: Make sure you specified a valid service shortname*)

So it basically can't find the service shortname which I specified. Does it prints (sc query) the real shortname of a service? Why doesn't it finds it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It failed to restrict the service because I lacked administrator privileges. Ran it as administrator and worked.